# How to authenticate OR secure data over URL using PHP CURL?

Tags: php, api, curl, php-curl

I have some confusion in CURL authentication. My case is below

```
https://example.com/data.php
```

I am sending data from my side in the above URL, I want to make this data accessible only for authenticate or limited person. Currently, everyone can access data when hit above URL.

Can anyone help me how can I achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: You can start by reading a guide: 
https://restfulapi.net/security-essentials/
There are a lot of ways.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass auth key which is generated by local. And in data.php, you can check the same key.

https://example.com/data.php?auth_key=12345

in data.php,

```
  if($_REQUEST['auth_key']!='12345') {
       header("Location: deny.php");
       die;
  }
```